# Method nonvisibility in base class despite definition in derived class; polymorphism and using `virtual` keyword

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, c++03

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class A {
    protected:
        int foo;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int bar) { foo = bar; }
        int method() { return foo; }
};

class C {
    private:
        A baz;
    public:
        C(A faz) { baz = faz; }
        A get() { return baz; }
};

int main(void) {
    C boo(B(1));
    std::cout << boo.get().method() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a base class `A` which `B` is a derived class of. Class `C` takes an `A` yet I have passed a derived class (`B`) in its place. No warnings or errors passing a `B` to `C`, but I'd like to have method visibility of `method()` in the above situation.

I'm not very familiar with `virtual` but I did try to add `virtual int method() = 0;` to `A` which lead to further errors.

Consider were I to add a second derived class:

```cpp
class D : public A {
    public:
        D(int bar) { foo = bar; }
        int method() { return foo+1; }
};
```

I'd like `C` to be able to take either `B` or `D` and my best assumption would be to take an `A` and let it handle it.

How do I use polymorphism correctly in this fashion?

Expected output with the below:

```cpp
int main(void) {
    C boo(B(1));
    C boz(D(2));
    std::cout << boo.get().method() << std::endl;
    std::cout << boz.get().method() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Would be:

```
1
3
```

Comment: Polymorphism only works with pointers or references. You need to store a `A&` or `A*` or equivalent in `C`. Usually I would have recommended `std::unique_ptr<A>`, but you tagged C++03. Can you really not upgrade to C++11? You also need to add a `virtual` constructor to `A`.

Comment: @walnut I am indeed limited by a C++03 constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to use `A` polymorphically, you need to add a `virtual` destructor, otherwise you will run into undefined behavior when trying to destroy the object. Then the method that you want to call through `A` must be `virtual` as well. If it shouldn't have an implementation in the base class itself, make it pure virtual:

```
class A {
    protected:
        int foo;
    public:
        virtual ~A() {}
        virtual int method() = 0;
};
```

Then in `C` you need to use pointers or references to `A`, since polymorphism only works with those.

If you want `C` to own the `A`, as your code example to suggest, then you need to provide a destructor deleting the pointer and you need to disable copying of the class (or decide on some useful semantics for it):

```
class C {
    private:
        C(const C&); // Don't allow copying
        C& operator=(const C&); // Don't allow copying
        A* baz;
    public:
        C(A* faz) : baz(faz) { }
        ~C() { delete baz; } 
        A& get() { return *baz; }
};

int main(void) {
    C boo(new B(1));
    C boz(new D(2));
    std::cout << boo.get().method() << std::endl;
    std::cout << boz.get().method() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally you would upgrade to C++11 and use `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of `A*` as member. But even if you can't do that, consider using `boost::scoped_ptr<A>`, which will manage the deletion for you (you don't need the destructor) and will make the class non-copyable by default. It also provides better exception-safety to encapsulate allocations in smart pointers like that.

Comment: Is `A` considered a pure abstract class, then? Can I still define methods in `A` that are not virtual?

Comment: @gator You can always define non-virtual methods. Yes it is an abstract class if at least one function is pure abstract, but that only means that you cannot create any objects of type `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've accepted it but I have one lingering thought: would disallowing assignment be necessary provided the code is strong? I wonder about arrays: `C boo[8]; boo[0] = new B(1);` works well in my code when I don't know of any other way to initialize an array element other than with `=`. `boo[0](new B(1));` doesn't work, clearly. If code is predictable and only instances of this occur (where assignment is correct), is the argument of "undefined behavior" still applicable?

Comment: @gator It would probably be safer to give `C` a default construtor setting the pointer to `NULL` and an `assign` method (or `operator=` overload taking an `A` pointer), which `delete`s the current `baz` and replaces it with the new one. The problem with the copy operations is that only either the source or the destination can own the pointer to the `A` object. So if copying transfers ownership, that might be surprising. (see `std::auto_ptr`, a pre-C++11 smart pointer that behaved this way). If you want to be able to copy with correct semantics use something like `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call method() of type B using base class type A there has to be lookup during the **runtime**. The lookup is necessary to answer the question: Which method should be called? - the one that corresponds the type in a current line? Or other method in inheritance hierarchy?" If you expect method() from class B to be called when you have pointer or reference to A then you have to create a lookup table. This table is called vtable (from virtual functions table) and it's defined by adding virtual keyword to functions.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        virtual ~A(){}
        virtual int method() = 0;
    protected:
        int foo;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        B(int bar) { foo = bar; }
        int method() { 
            std::cout << "Calling method() from B" << std::endl;
            return foo; }
};

class C {
    private:
        A* baz;
    public:
        C(A* faz) { baz = faz; }
        A* get() { return baz; }
};

int main(void) {
    A* element = new B(1);
    C boo(element);
    boo.get()->method();
    return 0;
}
```

It prints "Calling method() from B". Please keep in mind that the code is for presentation purposes and it's not good from best practices perspective.